# Como fazer para que o Ionic DevApp consiga listar os aplicativos na rede?

Tags: ionic, docker

Estou rodando uma instalação do Ionic dentro de um container Docker. Liberei as portas necessárias no container, tanto que consigo acessar o aplicativo pelo celular a partir do Ionic DevApp, basta informar IP e porta, entretanto, o Ionic DevApp não consegue automaticamente listar os apps publicados na rede, fica mostrando a mensagem: *Listening for apps on your network*...

Ao que tudo indica não me parece ser um problema de comunicação com o container/app. Segue string utilizar para construir o container:

```
docker run -it -p 8100:8100 -p 35729:35729 -p 53703:53703 --name nome_do_container fabiojanio/ionic /bin/bash
```

Também tentei utilizar o parâmetro `--net host`, mas isso não resolveu.

Versão dos softwares utilizados:

- Node 8.12.0
- Ionic DevApp 1.0.2
- Ionic Framework 3.20.0
- Docker version 18.06.1-ce
- SO MacOS Mojava 10.14

Comment: Veja se essa dica ajuda em algo: Adicionar o valor `https://{localeIP}:8100` em `allowedOrigins` -> [Ionic DevApp Feedback Mega-thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-devapp-feedback-mega-thread/109842/55)

Comment: @PedroGaspar Onde fica esse allowedOrigins?

Comment: Na verdade eu não sei, só achei a informação e repassei para ver se era útil. Mas, pesquisando agora, parece ir em algum arquivo de config, aparentemente, veja esses dois links: [Ionic 2 CORS issue](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-cors-issue/59815) e [Scala 403 issue on Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43408263/8133067).